# Difference behaviour when passing a value or a macro

Tags: strings, white-space

I am trying to fill in a form using the OCRB font. I need to add space after every digit in the amount. Below my command to do so:

```
\newcommand*\giro@bvramount[1]{
  \let\@tempa\relax
  \@tfor\@tempb:=#1\do {\@tempa \@tempb \let\@tempa\ }%
}
```

When I invoke the command with a number, it works as expected:

```
\giro@bvramount{485.99}
-> '4 8 5 . 9 9'
```

But when I use a macro, if doesn't work:

```
\def\@amount{485.99}
\giro@bvramount{\@amount}
-> '485.99'
```

The actual call in context is:

```
\hfill\ocrb\giro@bvramount{\giro@amount}
```

I would appreciate understanding what's going on here :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have at least partially working code to start from.

Comment: This said, I think that you just need `\expandafter\giro@bvramount\expandafter{\@amount}`.

Comment: To understand "what's going on here," you must understand the idea that in TeX, arguments to macros are not automatically pre-expanded, but are digested "as is".  Thus, if you asked, how many `4`'s are in `485.99`, you would conclude `1`.  But if you `\def\@amount{485.99}` and asked,  how many `4`'s are in `\@amount`, the answer would be zero, unless the macro knew to expand `\@amount` before conducting the search.  The `\expandafter` syntax suggested by Andrew is the way of telling TeX to expand `\@amount` (1 time) before it reaches the `\giro@bvramount` macro.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it in two steps:

```
\newcommand*\giro@bvramountaux[1]{%
  \let\@tempa\relax
  \@tfor\@tempb:=#1\do {\@tempa \@tempb \let\@tempa\ }%
}
\newcommand*\giro@bvramount[1]{%
  \expandafter\giro@bvramount\expandafter{#1}%
}
```

then both `\giro@bvramount{485.99}` and `\giro@bvramount\@amount` will work.

However, this is not the best way to proceed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\giro@bvramount@aux[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\giro@bvramount@auxi#1\@nil}%
}
\def\giro@bvramount@auxi#1#2\@nil{%
  #1%
  \@tfor\next:=#2\do{ \next}%
}
\newcommand*\giro@bvramount[1]{%
  \expandafter\giro@bvramount@aux\expandafter{#1}%
}

\def\@amount{485.99}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
X\giro@bvramount{485.99}X

X\giro@bvramount\@amount X

X\giro@bvramount{\@amount}X

X\giro@bvramount{1}X
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `expl3` it's obviously easier:

```
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \giro_bvramount:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpa_tl {} { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnx { Nnn }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Thanks egreg for taking the time to explain. I feel more intelligent now :-)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to first expand `\@amount` before giving it to `\giro@bvramount`. Here's a way do this using [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\InsertSpaces[1]{
  \tl_set:No \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { . } { \0\  } \l_tmpa_tl
  \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \InsertSpaces{485.99}

  \def\amount{485.99}
  \InsertSpaces{\amount}

\end{document}
```

The `o` in `\tl_set:No` says that `#1` should be expanded once and then `\l_tmpa_tl` is set equal to whatever this is.

Comment: I would not use regexes for this. You should refine the search expression not to include the last character.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Andrew. And yes I will add MWEs to my next requests. As the current has already been covered, I'll skip this one if ok :-)